# Film with a female android pilot that is destroyed near the start

Tags: story-identification, movie

This film is probably from the 70s or 80s and I think was American. All I remember is the hero encounters a couple (male and female, apparently human) in a spaceship on a planet. I *think* the spaceship interior was orange and the male pilot is a cowboy.

There is a battle going on around the spaceship and the female android is destroyed, I think by laser fire. It's only at this moment that we realise it was not a real woman. The male pilot mutters something about it being shame the robot is dead but in a kind of "shrugging of the shoulders" way.

And then the movie continues with no further reference to the android. It has a kind of [Battle Beyond the Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Beyond_the_Stars) vibe (ie not high quality effects) and is live action.

I can't find anything like it on Google and am beginning to wonder if I really watched it<sup>1</sup>. Does this sound familiar?

<sub>1 Or if my memory circuits are glitching.</sub>

Comment: This isn't a total match so I'll not post it as an answer but the question reminds me of https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086346/ - Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone

Comment: @Alith - that's it! Complete with *"[You were the best damn model they ever put out!](https://archive.org/details/SpacehunterOldSciFiFilm)"*. Please post it as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: the *answer* is the same. The question is quite different! :)

Comment: @Wikis: Yeah. It is funny how that can happen. But policy is that it's the answers matching that makes it a Duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the OP's comment the film they are looking for is [Spacehunter: Adventures in the Foridden Zone](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086346/).

This American film was released in 1983 and so fits the timeframe.

From the IMDB summary:

> Three women make an emergency landing on a planet plagued with a fatal disease, but are captured by dictator Overdog. Adventurer Wolff goes there to rescue them and meets Niki, the only Earthling left from a medical expedition. Combining their talents, they try to rescue the women.

The female android is Wolff's original companion (named Chalmers), she is indeed killed early on in the film after the spaceship lands.  Her death occurs (iirc) during a laser battle, while Wolff is on reconnaissance.  On his return we discover that Chalmers is an android and Wolff mutters ["*You were the best damn model they ever put out!"*](https://archive.org/details/SpacehunterOldSciFiFilm).

Thanks to @Wikis for the confirmation, I wasn't sure originally that this was the correct answer.

Comment: This was my initial thought also upon reading the post..